# Replace every string in dataframe containing character(s)

Tags: r, string, replace

In the test dataframe below, I am attempting to change every string in the dataframe containing "NA" to "" (so as to make NAs blank).

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=2, nrow=2))
dat$V1 <- c("  NA", "foo")
dat$V2 <- c("bar", "NA   ")

dat
   V1   V2
1  NA  bar
2 foo NA
```

However, the following command returns a completely blank dataframe, as if all strings contained "NA". Why does this happen and what would be the correct solution?

```
value <- "NA"

dat[grepl(value, dat)] <- ""
```

Comment: You are replacing by column here...

Comment: To explain Damiano's comment further, you're replacing columns with "" if they contain "NA". Since every column contains "NA", you are of course left with a blank dataframe. Note the difference if you construct a dataframe with `dat$V1 <- c("  NA", "NA  ")` and `dat$V2 <- c("foo", "bar  ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using gsub

```
value <- "NA" 

for (i in 1:ncol(dat)) {
  dat[,i] <- gsub(value, "", dat[,i])  
}
dat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) {gsub("NA", "", x)})
dat <- data.frame(dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

for(j in seq_along(dat)){
  set(dat, i = which(dat[[j]] %like% "NA"), j = j, value = "")
}
      V1  V2
# 1:     bar
# 2: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your case you are better off with a matrix.

```
datm <- as.matrix(dat)
```

Now your proposed solution works:

```
datm[grepl(value, datm)] <- ""
```

or using gsub:

```
datm = gsub("\\s*NA\\s*", "",datm)
```

You can convert it to a dataframe after data cleansing.